# Convergence of a Expectation Maximisation Algorithm

Tags: self-study, convergence, expectation-maximization

Consider using standard expectation maximisation to learn the parameters of a Hidden Markov Model. We can show the effect of standard expectation-maximisation on the log-likelihood by first writing the log-likelihood of data $x$ given hidden variables $z$ and parameters $\theta$ as

$\begin{align} L(\theta) = p_\theta(x) &= \sum_z q(z) \log{p_\theta(x)} \\ &= \sum_z q(z) \log{ \left( p_\theta(x) p_\theta(z|x) \frac{q(z)}{p_\theta(z|x)} \frac{1}{q(z)} \right)} \\ &= \sum_z q(z) \log{p_\theta(x,z)} + \sum_z q(z) \log{\frac{q(z)}{p_\theta(z|x)}} - \sum_z q(z) \log{q(z)} \\ &= \sum_z q(z) \log{p_\theta(x,z)} +KL(q||p_\theta(\cdot|x)) - H(q)   \end{align}$

At this point $q(z)$ is any valid probability distribution. We can choose it to be $q(z) = p_{\theta_0}(z|x)$ i.e. the posterior over hidden states just with a different choice of parameter. We then get

$\begin{align} L(\theta) &= \sum_z p_{\theta_0}(z|x) \log{p_\theta(x,z)} +KL(p_{\theta_0}(\cdot|x)||p_\theta(\cdot|x)) - H(p_{\theta_0}(\cdot|x)) \\ \\ &= E_{\theta_0} \left[ \log{p_\theta ( X,Z|X=x)} \right] +KL(p_{\theta_0}(\cdot|x)||p_\theta(\cdot|x)) - H(p_{\theta_0}(\cdot|x))   \\ &\geq E_{\theta_0} \left[ \log{p_\theta ( X,Z|X=x)} \right]- H(p_{\theta_0}(\cdot|x))  \\ &= Q(\theta,\theta_0) + g(\theta_0) \end{align}$

since the KL divergence is always non-negative.

This gives us two identities:

(1) $L(\theta) \geq Q(\theta, \theta_0) + g(\theta_0)$

(2) $L(\theta) = Q(\theta, \theta) + g(\theta)$

We can use these to show that

$\begin{align} L(\theta_t) &= Q(\theta_t, \theta_t) + g(\theta_t) \qquad \text{by (2)} \\ &\leq \text{max}_\theta Q(\theta,\theta_t) + g(\theta_t) \\ &= Q(\theta_{t+1},\theta_t) + g(\theta_t) \qquad \text{defining $\theta_{t+1} = \text{argmax}_\theta Q(\theta,\theta_t)$} \\ &\leq L(\theta_{t+1}) \qquad \text{by (1)} \end{align}$

So this proves that each iteration of standard expectation-maximisation never decreases the likelihood. There are now two possibilities:

(i) the log-likelihood increases forever
(ii) the log-likelihood converges

I believe that it should converge (at least that's what I've read) but I have not had any success in trying to show this. I'll accept any proof of convergence but if we could show it using free energy converging to some asymptote then that would be particularly helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but do not all monotone and bounded sequences necessarily converge?

Comment: @nope But I haven't established an upper bound for the sequence yet.

Comment: $L(\theta)$ is upper bounded by 0 (log of a Probability), doesn't that solve the problem ?